# Stack line on area / stack area on line in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

It is possible to stack a line on an area or an area on a line?

If this is not possible, is it planned to do later?

Best regards,
Gaël

(Update) Try to modify the exemple : highcharts_doc/demo/area-stacked
Replace a area by a line like this : http://jsfiddle.net/uq9HM/

```
            type: 'line',
            stacking: 'normal',
```

I can't stack line on area or area on line.

highcharts_doc/demo/combo-dual-axes is not a an answer is you wan't stack line and area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, it's not supported. You can stack only the same series type. However, you can set transparent color for area, see: http://jsfiddle.net/uq9HM/1/

```
        series: [{
            name: 'Asia',
            data: [502, 635, 809, 947, 1402, 3634, 5268]
        }, {
            name: 'Africa',
            data: [106, 107, 111, 133, 221, 767, 1766]
        }, {
            name: 'Europe',
            fillColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
            data: [163, 203, 276, 408, 547, 729, 628]
        }, {
            name: 'America',
            data: [18, 31, 54, 156, 339, 818, 1201]
        }, {
            name: 'Oceania',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }]
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few demos of this on the HighCharts website... take a look here, for example: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-dual-axes

You can see the code by clicking "view options" or "edit in jsFiddle."

Comment: The question is stack line and area not Dual axes, line and column. Try it with this for exemple : http://jsfiddle.net/uq9HM/

Comment: My intention was simply to show an example of how to stack things, not to say that the link I gave was the exact solution to your problem.

I'm not exactly sure why the jsfiddle link you just gave isn't working for you, though? You've got area series and then Europe is showing up as a line... isn't that what you wanted? If you want it to show up on top of the other series, just add "zIndex: 10" to the Europe series properties and it will show up on top.

Answer (score 1):

did you check with arearange type of graph

```
type: 'arearange',
```

here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3yg8b/

hope this will be useful for you